# Read char with sscanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

im trying to load a struct from a file register. When i try to scan a char i get a whitespace. The file register has this format:

accountNumber(char 8) code(char 1) balance(float 9 digits 2decimals)

Example :

AAAA1111 C 500000,05

When i try to get that example register i get:

AAAA1111 500000,05

```
typedef struct{
    char accountNum[8];
    char cod;
    float balance;
}t_regMov;

void loadStruct(char *line,t_regMov *mov){
    char *aux=line;
    aux=strchr(line,'\n');
    *aux='\0';
    aux-=9;
    sscanf(aux,"%f",&mov->balance);
    aux-=1;
    *aux='\0';
    aux-=1;
    sscanf(aux,"%c",&mov->cod);
    aux-=1;
    *aux='\0';
    sscanf(line,"%s",mov->accountNum);
}

int main(){
    FILE *movf=fopen("movements.txt","r+");
    if(!movf)exit(1);
    t_regMov mov;
    char line[100];

    fgets(line,sizeof(line),movf);
    while(!feof(movf)){
        loadStruct(line,&mov);
        printf("%s %c %f\n",mov.accountNum,mov.cod,mov.balance)
        fgets(line,sizeof(line),movf);
    }
    fclose(movf);
}
```

Comment: `char accountNum[8];` --> `char accountNum[8+1];`

Comment: Since you know the exact line format, `sscanf()` would appear to be overkill. I'd recommend using `memcpy()` and `atof()` to strip out the bits you need instead of `sscanf()`. On bigger projects I've been on, I've replaced all the text file format with something with more structure and with libraries that I had available to me. e.g. XML and JSON. If you need something more linear, there must be a good CSV library you can use? Working with specialist text files is prone to lead yourself to maintenance mayhem.

Comment: Also Probably `float` isn't enough accuracy.

Comment: `"%c"` --> `" %c"`  (Add space)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified example that parses the line you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {
        int left, right;
        char *accountNumber;
        char cod;
        sscanf("AAAA1111 C 500000,05", "%8s %c %d,%d", accountNumber, &cod,&left, &right);
        printf("Account: %s\nCode: %c\nBalance: %d,%d\n", accountNumber, cod, left, right);
}
```

The big change is that in your `sscanf` you can specify a max chars for the string buffer.  Like the comment above notes, you'll need to allocate the right amount of space for your strings (null termination and all).

Comment: `char accountNum[8];` or `char *accountNumber;` and `"%8s"` --> problems.  `accountNum[]` too small.